# ThinkPad second "sticky" backspace key

Tags: ubuntu, keyboard, thinkpad

I have bought a Lenovo ThinkPad T580, and noticed that in the upper right corner of the keyboard, there is a second backspace button (in addition to the other backspace button right above the ENTER-button), as can be seen in the picture.

[image: Second backspace button]

However when I press this button once, my operating system (Ubuntu 18.04) acts as if I'm keeping the backspace button pressed, and therefore deletes much more than I intend to. In addition to this, I have disabled my trackpad while typing, so if I press this button once, I cannot use my trackpad anymore until I lock my screen, at which point the "pressed" backspace button seems to be "released".

I am only experiencing this behaviour on Ubuntu, not on Windows (I'm dual booting Ubuntu 18.04 and Windows 10).

How would I disable this key, or disable the strange behaviour?

**UPDATE**
I have watched what happens when the key is pressed using `xev`. Both backspace keys provide the same output here, however the second backspace key is repeated over and over again, like it's in a `while(true);` loop. When I press any other key, the looping stops, but my trackpad is still disabled.

Comment: @dessert I am looking for a way to either disable the key, or fix the strange "sticky" backspace behaviour.

Comment: Look into [`xmodmap` questions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/xmodmap?sort=votes&pageSize=50), e.g.  [How can I change what keys on my keyboard do?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/254424/how-can-i-change-what-keys-on-my-keyboard-do-how-can-i-create-custom-keyboard)

Comment: @dessert the xev output is the same for both backspace keys, so I cannot remap the key.

Comment: Page 103 of the User Guide pdf at https://download.lenovo.com/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/t580_p52s_ug_en.pdf suggests that Windows relies on a "ThinkPad Hotkey Features" program to facilitate proper operation of the numeric keypad (the small backspace key is shown included as part of the numeric keyboard on page 38 of the pdf). If there's some distinct aspect of Ubuntu that handles function keys, that might be something to look at.

Comment: I have a Thinkpad L14 without numpad/second backspace. A moment ago my normal backspace started acting in the same way (as far as I could observe, didn't check `xev`). Even locking the screen didn't help. I was able to solve it by connecting an external keyboard, which gave back control to me (so it shouldn't be an physically stuck key). When I disconnected the keyboard it started backspacing again. So I did a `dnf upgrade` (Fedora 36)  for the newest software and restarted. Now it works again, but I don't know if it is fixed by the update or just reset by the restart and might happen again.

Answer (score 0):

I have a thinkpad X1 extreme, also without a second backspace key.  Sporadically, I've had backspace apparently stuck.  Jiggling backspace didn't do anything, and laptop is quite new, so I think it's not an actual physical key problem, but some software glitch where it looses the key-up.  Works normally 99% of time. Very annoying to see it methodically wipe out everything you've typed, and only solution I've found is rebooting.  Hasn't happened with any other key.  Will try plugging in second keyboard when it happens next time.